# How to vertically center contents of table cells

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I don't really understand how I can vertically align the contents of my table. They seem to be all messed up, and I dont know why. Here is a screenshot showing the problem:

[image]

And here is the code I am currently using to produce the shown table:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Malmoe}
\title{Tex Stack Exchange example}
\subject{Question about vertical centering tables}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\setlength\extrarowheight{4pt}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Statistics}{}
\tiny
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| L{1.8cm} | C{0.8cm} | C{0.8cm} | C{0.8cm} | C{0.8cm} | C{0.8cm}| C{0.8cm} | C{0.8cm} |}
\hline
Scenario & Number of events & Number of clusters & Number of healthy clusters & Number of unhealthy clusters & Number of clusters pairs & Number of real cluster pairs & Number of fake cluster pairs \\
\hline
Eff. 76\%  total/module 1/module 4 & 9079 & 36855956 2191062 2917431 & 30235384 495474 1781164 & 6620572 1695588 1136267 & 1347578 513532 92623 & 28242 3407 4090 & 1319336 510125 88533  \\
\hline
Eff. 90\%  total/module 1/module 4 & 8285 & 33935939 1926868 2923980 & 29137926 711464 2148856 & 4798013 1215404 775124 & 1063412 397880 72455 & 26928 3100 4307 & 1036484 394780 68148  \\
\hline
Eff. 100\% total/module 1/module 4 & 9883 & 40379644 214092 366267 & 36443709 119498 3085536 & 3935935 945942 577141 & 896456 320005 59953 & 32121 3484 5551 & 864335 316521 54402  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Can you help me what I should do about the array box centering to fix the "messed up" alignment in the table cells? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hello Adam, removing the `\hspace{0pt}` in the line `\newcolumntype{C} ...` worked to me.  Alas, I don't know why. :-(

Comment: Make the columns with the displaced entries a bit wider. The 8 digit numbers are wider than 0.8cm (there should be overfull hbox warnings in the log file), so TeX breaks the line between `\hspace{0pt}` and the long number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you

- remove the instructions `\let\newline\\` and `\hspace{0pt}` from the definitions of the `L`, `C`, and `R` column types and
- set `\extrarowheight` to a more reasonable value, say,

  ```
  \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
  ```

A revised MWE -- I've changed some of the columns widths to allow proper centering of the material.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Malmoe}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % 4pt seems excessive...

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Statistics}{}
\tiny
\centering
\begin{tabular}{| L{1.7cm} | C{0.7cm} | C{0.9cm} | *{5}{C{0.8cm}|} }
\hline
Scenario & Number of events & Number of clusters & Number of healthy clusters & Number of unhealthy clusters & Number of cluster pairs & Number of real cluster pairs & Number of fake cluster pairs \\
\hline
Eff.\ 76\%~total\slash module~1\slash module~4 & 9079 & 36855956 2191062 2917431 & 30235384 495474 1781164 & 6620572 1695588 1136267 & 1347578 513532 92623 & 28242 3407 4090 & 1319336 510125 88533  \\
\hline
Eff.\ 90\%~total\slash module~1\slash module~4 & 8285 & 33935939 1926868 2923980 & 29137926 711464 2148856 & 4798013 1215404 775124 & 1063412 397880 72455 & 26928 3100 4307 & 1036484 394780 68148  \\
\hline
Eff.\ 100\%~total\slash module~1\slash module~4 & 9883 & 40379644 214092 366267 & 36443709 119498 3085536 & 3935935 945942 577141 & 896456 320005 59953 & 32121 3484 5551 & 864335 316521 54402  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a variant, using the `\Gape` command, from `makecell`  to give some vertical padding at the top and bottom of cells. I've put the repetitive ‘Number of` as a general heading for the last 7 columns:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Malmoe}
\usepackage{array, makecell, bigstrut}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\tiny}

\begin{document}

\setcellgapes{5pt}
\begin{frame}{Statistics}{}
\tiny
\centering
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{| l | c | C{0.9cm} | *{5}{C{0.8cm}|} }
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{7}{c}{\scriptsize Number of}\\[1ex]%
\hline
 Scenario & Events & Clusters & Healthy clusters & Unhealthy clusters & Cluster pairs & \rule{0pt}{2.6ex}Real cluster pairs \rule[-1.2ex]{0pt}{2.5ex} & \rule{0pt}{2.6ex}Fake cluster pairs \rule[-1.2ex]{0pt}{2.5ex} \\
\hline
\Gape[3pt][2pt]{\makecell[lc]{Eff.\ 76\,\%~total\slash\\ module~1\slash\\ module~4}} & 9079 & 36855956 2191062 2917431 & 30235384 495474 1781164 & 6620572 1695588 1136267 & 1347578 513532 92623 & 28242 3407 4090 & 1319336 510125 88533 \\
\hline
\Gape[3pt][2pt]{\makecell[lc]{Eff.\ 90\,\%~total\slash\\ module~1\slash\\ module~4}} & 8285 & 33935939 1926868 2923980 & 29137926 711464 2148856 & 4798013 1215404 775124 & 1063412 397880 72455 & 26928 3100 4307 & 1036484 394780 68148 \\
\hline
\Gape[3pt][2pt]{\makecell[lc]{Eff.\ 100\,\%~total\slash\\ module~1\slash\\ module~4}} & 9883 & 40379644 214092 366267 & 36443709 119498 3085536 & 3935935 945942 577141 & 896456 320005 59953 & 32121 3484 5551 & 864335 316521 54402 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A version with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. The key `hvlines` draws all the rules.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Malmoe}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Statistics}{}
\tiny
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{L{1.7cm}C{0.7cm}C{0.9cm}*{5}{C{0.8cm}}}[hvlines]
Scenario & Number of events & Number of clusters & Number of healthy clusters & Number of unhealthy clusters & Number of cluster pairs & Number of real cluster pairs & Number of fake cluster pairs \\
Eff.\ 76\%~total\slash module~1\slash module~4 & 9079 & 36855956 2191062 2917431 & 30235384 495474 1781164 & 6620572 1695588 1136267 & 1347578 513532 92623 & 28242 3407 4090 & 1319336 510125 88533  \\
Eff.\ 90\%~total\slash module~1\slash module~4 & 8285 & 33935939 1926868 2923980 & 29137926 711464 2148856 & 4798013 1215404 775124 & 1063412 397880 72455 & 26928 3100 4307 & 1036484 394780 68148  \\
Eff.\ 100\%~total\slash module~1\slash module~4 & 9883 & 40379644 214092 366267 & 36443709 119498 3085536 & 3935935 945942 577141 & 896456 320005 59953 & 32121 3484 5551 & 864335 316521 54402  \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]